# Sending 404 and 400 from mongoose server

Tags: c, http, http-headers, mongoose-web-server

Hi I am working on an embedded server using mongoose server. I have the following code from [Mongoose Doc](http://cesanta.com/docs/Embed.shtml).

```
#include <string.h>
#include "mongoose.h"

static int event_handler(struct mg_connection *conn, enum mg_event ev) {
  if (ev == MG_AUTH) {
    return MG_TRUE;   // Authorize all requests
  } else if (ev == MG_REQUEST && !strcmp(conn->uri, "/hello")) {
      mg_printf_data(conn, "%s", "Hello world");
    return MG_TRUE;   // Mark as processed
  } else {
    return MG_FALSE;  // Rest of the events are not processed
  }
}

int main(void) {
  struct mg_server *server = mg_create_server(NULL, event_handler);
  //mg_set_option(server, "document_root", ".");
  mg_set_option(server, "listening_port", "8080");

  for (;;) {
    mg_poll_server(server, 1000);  // Infinite loop, Ctrl-C to stop
  }
  mg_destroy_server(&server);

  return 0;
}
```

This code work perfectly. After sending "Hello World", MG_POLL stops. and chrome shows loading finished. But when I try to send the error code by replacing the mg_printf with

```
mg_printf(conn,"HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n"
                 "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
                 "Connection: close\r\nCache-control: private\r\n"
                 "Server: lighttpd/1.4.26\r\n\r\n"
                 "<html><body>"
                 "<h2>OOPS !!!!</h2>"
                 "<p>Check the url... Url is malformed</p>"
                 "</body></html>");
```

The polling never stops and in chrome its shows still loading. Is there any thing additional required for sending custom error codes?

---

After adding

```
void mg_send_status(struct mg_connection *, int status_code);
void mg_send_header(struct mg_connection *, const char *name, const char *value);
void mg_send_data(struct mg_connection *, const void *data, int data_len);
void mg_printf_data(struct mg_connection *, const char *format, ...);
```

The loading problem is fixed. But the event_handler is getting called repeatedly. Its more like not getting CLOSE.  when I try closing the browser window the connection is getting closed and call back stops

Comment: ``void mg_send_status(struct mg_connection *, int status_code);
void mg_send_header(struct mg_connection *, const char *name,
                    const char *value);
void mg_send_data(struct mg_connection *, const void *data, int data_len);
void mg_printf_data(struct mg_connection *, const char *format, ...);`` I think those are the functions you want to use.

Comment: @BitTickler I have tried the functions and it fixes the loading in chrome. But the poll is not stopping.

Comment: you mean ``mg_poll_server()``? It won't ever stop until you leave your loop. The server is actively driven like a render loop in some game. It is not event driven.

Comment: @BitTickler Not mg_poll_server.. My issue is that, even after sending the error code, the  event_handler is getting invoked with ev = MG_POLL

Comment: its more like bower is not closing the connection. When i close the Browser, event_handler receives a MG_CLOSE and the call back stops